# JAVA - Answers are not calculating upon output?

Tags: java, output, pi

Doing a what I thought would be a very very easy output lab for AP, I thought I was doing everything correctly, but the output keeps coming out as "The area is :: " + 0.0" when the "0.0" is supposed to be the calculated area of the circle. Here are the two classes:

Circle Class:

```
public class Circle
{
    private double radius;
    private double area;

    public void setRadius(double rad)
    {
        rad = radius;
    }

    public void calculateArea( )
    {
        area = (3.14159*(radius*radius));
    }

    public void print( )
    {
       System.out.println("The area is :: " + area);
    }
}
```

Circle Runner Class:

```
public class CircleRunner
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
   {
        Circle test = new Circle ( );
        test.setRadius(7.5);
        test.calculateArea( );
        test.print( );

        test.setRadius(10);
        test.calculateArea( );
        test.print( );

        test.setRadius(72.534);
        test.calculateArea( );
        test.print( );

        test.setRadius(55);
        test.calculateArea( );
        test.print( );
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your setter is wrong, so your radius stays 0, it should be

```
public void setRadius(double rad) {
    radius = rad;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the variables in reverse order. It should be:

```
radius = rad;
```

And not:

```
rad = radius;
```

Comment: Also, I think a question like this is best suited to the [Code Review Site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), and you should improve your coding conventions to avoid this type of mistake (using "this" qualifier for example).

Comment: No, CodeReview reviews working code. Instead he is asking why his code doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this to reference your radius in your setRadius Method. or swap the two values. You should assign  " rad " to " radius" and not vis versa, since you will be recieving rad from the method.

```
public class Circle {
    private double radius;
    private double area;

    public  Circle() {
    }

    public void setRadius(double rad) {
        this.radius = rad;
    }

    public void calculateArea() {
        area = (3.14159*(radius*radius));
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("The area is :: " + area);
    }
}
```